# Using NULL statement in a function parameter

Tags: c, function, null

I am just doing a revision task and was running into the error too few arguments to function, so I did some research and apparently can use NULL for the statement not in use. However, when I run my program all that happens is the prompt for the user to enter the 3 values then it ends. It doesn't perform the calculations.

Below is my code, if anyone can help with that, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float res_calculation (float r1, float r2, float r3, float* RS, float* RP )
{
    *RS = (r1+r2+r3);
    *RP = (r1*r2*r3)/(r1*r2+r2*r3+r1*r3);
    
    
    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    float r1,r2,r3,rs,rp;
    printf("Please enter the values for r1, r2 and r3 seperated by a space");
    scanf ("%f %f %f", &r1, &r2, &r3);
    
    res_calculation(r1,r2,r3,&rs,NULL);
    printf("%f",rs);
    
    res_calculation(r1,r2,r3,&rp,NULL);
    printf("%f",rp);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `NULL` is a macro, not a statement.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing `NULL` for the `RP` parameter of `res_calculation`.  This parameter is a pointer which the function subsequently dereferences.  So if you pass a NULL pointer, the function will attempt to dereference a NULL pointer which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to pass a valid pointer value for this parameter, i.e.

```
res_calculation(r1,r2,r3,&rs,&rp);
```

Comment: Or, inside the function, test `if (RP != NULL) *RP = …`.

Comment: Thank you, I had previously had my res_calculation as you mentioned above but then i would get the error, 'too few arguments to function'.

Answer (score 0):

If a `NULL` pointer to the function parameter could mean "I don't care for a result stored here", then test for `NULL` in the function.

```
float res_calculation (float r1, float r2, float r3, float* RS, float* RP ) {
    if (RS) *RS = (r1+r2+r3);
    if (RP) *RP = (r1*r2*r3)/(r1*r2+r2*r3+r1*r3);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, code could use a *compound literal* for temporary storage.

```
res_calculation(r1, r2, r3, &rs, &(float){0});
printf("%f", rs);

res_calculation(r1 ,r2, r3, &(float){0}, &rp);
printf("%f", rp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
float res_calculation(float r1, float r2, float r3, float* RS, float* RP)
{
    *RS = (r1 + r2 + r3);

    if(RP != NULL)
        *RP = (r1 * r2 * r3) / (r1 * r2 + r2 * r3 + r1 * r3);

    return 0;
}
```

so that if RP is equal to NULL it will not be considered by the function.

Alternatively, you can pass the pointer to RP and simply ignore its value. What you **cannot** do is try to dereference a NULL pointer as you did in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. only calls the `res_calculation()` function once
4. changes the return type for the `res_calculation()` from `float` to `void` and removes the `return` statement because nothing useful is being returned and `main()` is not checking for any returned value.
5. properly checks for I/O errors on the call to `scanf()` and reports any errors to the user via the `stderr` output stream.
6. adds a '\n' to the format parameter of the calls to `printf()` so the calculated values are immediately passed to the terminal, rather than waiting until after the program exits

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void res_calculation (float r1, float r2, float r3, float* RS, float* RP )
{
    *RS = (r1+r2+r3);
    *RP = (r1*r2*r3)/(r1*r2+r2*r3+r1*r3);
}


int main( void )
{
    float r1,r2,r3,rs,rp;
    printf("Please enter the values for r1, r2 and r3 seperated by a space");
    if( scanf ("%f %f %f", &r1, &r2, &r3) != 3 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for three float values failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    res_calculation( r1, r2, r3, &rs, &rp );
    printf("RS: %f\n",rs);
    printf("RP: %f\n",rp);
      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your a legend cant stress enough how much this helps.